# Use of would vs will?

Tags: conditionals, will-would

What's the different between would and will? For example:

> How would it be?
>   How will it be?

When should I use one vs the other?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60758/the-third-conditional-for-if-i-could/60807#60807

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205538/is-the-use-of-would-valid-when-describing-a-hypothetical-future-situation/205557#205557

Comment: Please identify what you think the difference is and why you are not sure. The [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) will give you guidance on how to use this site. Also, questions for English Language Learners should be taken to [our sister site](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) — but please read their submission guidelines as well.